# Custom QStandardItemModel invisibleRootItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm using `pyqt` and I would like to use a reimplemented `QStandardItem` as `invisibleRootItem`, is there a way to reimplement the way the model creates its `invisibleRootItem`?

Comment: The root item is defined as `QScopedPointer<QStandardItem>` and is not affected by `setItemPrototype`, so the answer would appear to be "no". Looks like you'd have to implement your own item-based model, if you really want this.